# ReactJS progress bar animated

Tags: css, reactjs, css-transitions

In my application I have build a progress bar which is used in my wizard for 3 scenes. I've added a smooth transition by setting a class on the progress bar, it runs smooth when you navigate from step 1 to 2 and 2 to 3 but when you navigate back, it doesn't look that smooth as the transition doesn't run backward.

My question to this problem is, how do I backward this process to know where the user was before, lets say step 3 and it goes back to stap 2, transition needs to work backwards for smoothness.

Should I store some value in the localStorage to keep tracking the user step? or is there another way around to handle this backward working for transitions?

**ReactJS ProcessBar**

```
import React from 'react';
import classnames from 'classnames';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class ProgressBar extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            scenes: {
            step_1: props.step_1,
            step_2: props.step_2,
            step_3: props.step_3,
        },
        style: {
            width: props.progression,
                transition: 'all 1s ease'
            }
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        requestAnimationFrame(()=> {
            this.setProgression();
            this.setActiveScene();
        });
    }

    setProgression() {
        var style = {};
        style.width = this.props.progression;
        style.transition = 'all 1s ease';
    }

    setActiveScene() {
        var scenes = {};
        scenes.step_1 = this.props.step_1;
        scenes.step_2 = this.props.step_2;
        scenes.step_3 = this.props.step_3;
    }

    /**
     *
     * Render
     * @return {JSX}
     */
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="progress-bar">
                <div className="progress-bar__inner">

                    <div className="progress-bar__progress">
                        <div className="progress-bar__progress-fill" style={this.state.style}></div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="sceneStep1" className={classnames('progress-bar__element', this.state.step_1)}>
                        <i className="progress-bar__icon"></i>
                        <span className="progress-bar__label">
                            <Link to="/step_1">Step 1</Link>
                        </span>
                    </div>

                    <div id="sceneStep2" className={classnames('progress-bar__element', this.state.step_2)}>
                        <i className="progress-bar__icon"></i>
                        <span className="progress-bar__label">
                            <Link to="/step_2">Step 2</Link>
                        </span>
                    </div>

                    <div id="sceneStep3" className={classnames('progress-bar__element', this.state.step_3)}>
                        <i className="progress-bar__icon"></i>
                        <span className="progress-bar__label">
                            <Link to="/step_3">Step 3</Link>
                        </span>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default ProgressBar;


{/ReactJS Step 3 Component/}

    class Step_3 extends React.Component {
        /**
         *
         * Render
         * @return {XML}
         */
        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <Header/>
                        <ProgressBar step_1="done" step_2="done" step_3="active" />
                        Step 3
                    <Footer/>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
    
    export default Step_3;
```

Comment: This question is impossible to answer without knowing **how** you implemented the processbar component, the processbar animation and how the "steps" are implemented. Please add the code for that.

Comment: I have edit my question with example code

Comment: I would suggest changing the progress width dynamically with state style as suggested in the answer bellow and animate that with css

Comment: Thank you, I tried this but then my animation won't work

Answer (score 0):

I would use simple css transitions on some style property.
Example

```
 .progress-bar {
     -webkit-transition: width .3s ease;
     -o-transition: width .3s ease;
     transition: width .3s ease;
 }
```

And simply play around with the width of the whole progress bar.
I actually have something simillar but [written in vue](https://github.com/cristijora/vue-form-wizard/blob/master/src/components/FormWizard.vue#L162)

[Demo of how it works](https://jsfiddle.net/bt5dhqtf/97/)